# Where can I find a 90-degree elbow to connect to my ice maker water line?

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator, ice-maker

I currently have an ice maker box in my kitchen that is connected to a 1/4" compression fitting to a braided stainless steel tube that goes to my refrigerator.  The problem is that this ice maker box connector comes straight out of the wall directly behind the refrigerator and the refrigerator can't be moved far enough towards the wall without destructively bending the stainless steel tubing.  I'm looking for a 90-degree elbow that can connect to the ice maker box that will allow the stainless steel tubing to go straight up or to the side, thus allowing the refrigerator to move another inch or two closer to the wall (still giving enough clearance per the manual).

Is there any such elbow I can purchase that will allow me to make this sharp turn off the ice maker box?  I have not been able to find anything at my local hardware store or on the internet.  Or is there an alternate option I have not been considering?

Edit: I originally said this was a 1/2" comp connector, but it is actually 1/4".  [This](http://www.lowes.com/pd_247027-59288-98516_4294753274%2B4294820839__?productId=3190917) is the exact part I currently have installed.

Edit2: Does anyone know the proper name of this type of fitting?  Every time I search for compression fittings online, I just get the copper tubing type of fitting, not the threaded 1/4" fitting that I really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everyone just calm down.  you guys are looking for an arrow industries 05-57L-4-4

http://arrowindustries.com/content/catalog/2015/Arrow%20web%20catalog%20sec%20g.pdf

Comment: Do you know if this is an equivalent part?  https://www.plumbingsupply.com/images/compress-90-elbow-fipt-lg.jpg which is labeled as (1/4" x 1/4" FIPS 90° Elbow)

Comment: no - that has a 1/4" female inside pipe thread and 1/4" compression thread.  not the same thing